# Able to charge customer at a later time?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to set up the form where a customer is required to put their card info but we charge it a later time? If anyone has used jotform they allow a person to put down their card info then it sends a "token" to stripe letting it know that the card info has been submitted which can be charged at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Cognito Forms will not support collecting credit card data on the form. The payment would have to be processed by one our our payment gateways at the time the form is submitted.